# Pyparsing/Python Binary Boolean Expression to XML Nesting Issue (2.7.10)

Tags: python, xml, nested, boolean, pyparsing

I need to parse nested binary boolean expressions into an XML tree. For example take the expression

```
expression2 =  "((Param1 = 1 AND Param2 = 1 ) \
            OR (Param3 = 1 AND Param4 = 1)) \
            AND \
            (((Param5 = 0 AND Param6 = 1 )  \
            OR(Param7 = 0 AND Param8 = 1)) \
            AND \
            ((Param9 = 0 AND Param10 = 1 )  \
            OR(Param11 = 0 AND Param12 = 1)))"
```

which is essentially a combination of `(Expression) (Operator) (Expression)` terms.

I need the output to be a combination of these expressions with proper tags in XML.  aka

```
<MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>
            Parameter
          </FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>
            1
          </SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
```

where firstexpression can be a parameter or a mainbody (here is the nesting), operator is always =, <, >, AND, OR, and secondexpression is either an integer or a mainbody

There will always be groups of three - aka the smallest discrete object will consist of the firstexpression the operator and the second expression.

The code I've come up with (This is my first time using python) gets me somewhat there.

```
import pyparsing as pp
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


operator = pp.Regex(">=|<=|!=|>|<|=").setName("operator").setResultsName("Operator")
number = pp.Regex(r"[+-]?\d+(:?\.\d*)?(:?[eE][+-]?\d+)?").setResultsName("SecondExpression")
identifier = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_" + ".").setName("FirstExpression").setResultsName("FirstExpression")
comparison_term = identifier | number
condition = pp.Group(comparison_term + operator + comparison_term).setResultsName("MainBody")


expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition,[
                            ("NOT", 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, ),
                            ("AND", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ("OR", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ])


expression2 =  "((Param1 = 1 AND Param2 = 1 ) \
                OR (Param3 = 1 AND Param4 = 1)) \
                AND \
                (((Param5 = 0 AND Param6 = 1 )  \
                OR(Param7 = 0 AND Param8 = 1)) \
                AND \
                ((Param9 = 0 AND Param10 = 1 )  \
                OR(Param11 = 0 AND Param12 = 1)))"



out = expr.parseString(expression2)
text = out.asXML()

f = open('rules.xml','w+')
f.write(text) 
f.close()

root = ET.parse("rules.xml").getroot()

print ET.tostring(root)
```

This outputs XML of this form:

```
<ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <MainBody>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param1</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
        <ITEM>AND</ITEM>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param2</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
      </MainBody>
      <ITEM>OR</ITEM>
      <MainBody>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param3</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
        <ITEM>AND</ITEM>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param4</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
      </MainBody>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>AND</ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <MainBody>
          <MainBody>
            <FirstExpression>Param5</FirstExpression>
            <Operator>=</Operator>
            <SecondExpression>0</SecondExpression>
          </MainBody>
          <ITEM>AND</ITEM>
          <MainBody>
            <FirstExpression>Param6</FirstExpression>
            <Operator>=</Operator>
            <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
          </MainBody>
        </MainBody>
        <ITEM>OR</ITEM>
        <MainBody>
          <MainBody>
            <FirstExpression>Param7</FirstExpression>
            <Operator>=</Operator>
            <SecondExpression>0</SecondExpression>
          </MainBody>
          <ITEM>AND</ITEM>
          <MainBody>
            <FirstExpression>Param8</FirstExpression>
            <Operator>=</Operator>
            <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
          </MainBody>
        </MainBody>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>AND</ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <MainBody>
          <MainBody>
            <FirstExpression>Param9</FirstExpression>
            <Operator>=</Operator>
            <SecondExpression>0</SecondExpression>
          </MainBody>
          <ITEM>AND</ITEM>
          <MainBody>
            <FirstExpression>Param10</FirstExpression>
            <Operator>=</Operator>
            <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
          </MainBody>
        </MainBody>
        <ITEM>OR</ITEM>
        <MainBody>
          <MainBody>
            <FirstExpression>Param11</FirstExpression>
            <Operator>=</Operator>
            <SecondExpression>0</SecondExpression>
          </MainBody>
          <ITEM>AND</ITEM>
          <MainBody>
            <FirstExpression>Param12</FirstExpression>
            <Operator>=</Operator>
            <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
          </MainBody>
        </MainBody>
      </ITEM>
    </ITEM>
  </ITEM>
</ITEM>
```

Obviously this isn't want I want as the only objects with tags are at the deepest level. I need it to be as deep as necessary for much larger rules than this - essentially a binary tree with collections of Mainbody, FirstExpression, Operator, and Second Expression.

I also need to place integer values inside  tags which is another thing I haven't figure out how to do.

I think that pyparsing should be able to do this with groups somehow but I can't figure it out.

Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to achieve this?

Thanks

EDIT 11/5/15:

Building off of what Paul wrote I've arrived at this code with an (well intended to be) recursive grammar:

```
   import pyparsing as pp


operator = pp.oneOf(">= <= != > < =")("operator")
integer = pp.Regex(r"[+-]?\d+(:?\.\d*)?(:?[eE][+-]?\d+)?")("integer")
parameter = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_" + "." + "-")("parameter")
comparison_term = parameter | integer

firstExpression = pp.Forward()
secondExpression = pp.Forward()

mainbody = pp.Group(firstExpression + operator + secondExpression)("Mainbody")

firstExpression <<  pp.Group(parameter | pp.Optional(mainbody))("FirstExpression")
secondExpression << pp.Group(integer | pp.Optional(mainbody))("SecondExpression")

AND_ = pp.Keyword("AND")("operator")
OR_ = pp.Keyword("OR")("operator")
NOT_ = pp.Keyword("NOT")("operator")

expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(mainbody,[
                            (NOT_, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, ),
                            (AND_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            (OR_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ])

# undocumented hack to assign a results name to (expr) - RED FLAG
expr.expr.resultsName = "Mainbody"

expression1 = "((Param1 = 1) \
                OR  (Param2 = 1))"

out = expr.parseString(expression1)[0] # extract item 0 from single-item list
text = out.asXML("Mainbody") # add tag for outermost element
print text
```

Will infinity recurse. Changing the | to + in the firstExpression and secondExpression lines fixes this but I believe it causes the parser to never look for the mainbody to group.

I've included a simplified rule so I can show the exact output I'm trying to get.

This code generates:

```
 <Mainbody>
  <Mainbody>
    <FirstExpression>
      <parameter>Param1</parameter>
    </FirstExpression>
    <operator>=</operator>
    <SecondExpression>
      <integer>1</integer>
    </SecondExpression>
  </Mainbody>
  <operator>OR</operator>
  <Mainbody>
    <FirstExpression>
      <parameter>Param2</parameter>
    </FirstExpression>
    <operator>=</operator>
    <SecondExpression>
      <integer>1</integer>
    </SecondExpression>
  </Mainbody>
</Mainbody>
```

What I'm trying to get

```
  <Mainbody>
    <FirstExpression>
     <Mainbody>
      <FirstExpression>
       <parameter>Param1</parameter>
      </FirstExpression>
      <operator>=</operator>
      <SecondExpression>
       <integer>1</integer>
      </SecondExpression>
     </Mainbody>
    </FirstExpression>
    <operator>OR</operator>
    <SecondExpression> 
     <Mainbody>
      <FirstExpression>
       <parameter>Param2</parameter>
      </FirstExpression>
      <operator>=</operator>
      <SecondExpression>
       <integer>1</integer>
      </SecondExpression>
    </Mainbody>
   </SecondExpression>
  </Mainbody>
```

It looks the the issue I'm seeing is the parser isn't properly tagging/recognizing/grouping a mainbody as FirstExpression or SecondExpression. I've tried adjusting the grammar and often times get infinite recursion so I have a feeling something is wrong at my grammar definition. I need this to work for any number of binary grouped (PARAMETER = INTEGER) by AND/OR.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with just a few changes:

- change "AND", "OR", and "NOT" to Keyword expressions, with results name of "operator", so that they will get wrapped in `<operator>` tags
- hack a results name for the internal expression of the `expr` created by `operatorPrecedence` (which is recently renamed to `infixNotation`)
- extraction of the 0'th element from the single-item list returned from parseString
- add an outermost tag name in the call to asXML

.

```
operator = pp.oneOf(">= <= != > < =")("Operator")
number = pp.Regex(r"[+-]?\d+(:?\.\d*)?(:?[eE][+-]?\d+)?")("SecondExpression")
identifier = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_" + ".")("FirstExpression")
comparison_term = identifier | number
condition = pp.Group(comparison_term + operator + comparison_term)("MainBody")

# define AND, OR, and NOT as keywords, with "operator" results names
AND_ = pp.Keyword("AND")("operator")
OR_ = pp.Keyword("OR")("operator")
NOT_ = pp.Keyword("NOT")("operator")

expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition,[
                            (NOT_, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, ),
                            (AND_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            (OR_, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ])

# undocumented hack to assign a results name to (expr) - RED FLAG
expr.expr.resultsName = "group"

expression2 =  "((Param1 = 1 AND Param2 = 1 ) \
                OR (Param3 = 1 AND Param4 = 1)) \
                AND \
                (((Param5 = 0 AND Param6 = 1 )  \
                OR(Param7 = 0 AND Param8 = 1)) \
                AND \
                ((Param9 = 0 AND Param10 = 1 )  \
                OR(Param11 = 0 AND Param12 = 1)))"



out = expr.parseString(expression2)[0] # extract item 0 from single-item list
text = out.asXML("expression") # add tag for outermost element
print text
```

prints:

```
<expression>
  <group>
    <group>
      <MainBody>
        <FirstExpression>Param1</FirstExpression>
        <Operator>=</Operator>
        <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
      </MainBody>
      <operator>AND</operator>
      <MainBody>
        <FirstExpression>Param2</FirstExpression>
        <Operator>=</Operator>
        <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
      </MainBody>
    </group>
    <operator>OR</operator>
    <group>
      <MainBody>
        <FirstExpression>Param3</FirstExpression>
        <Operator>=</Operator>
        <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
      </MainBody>
      <operator>AND</operator>
      <MainBody>
        <FirstExpression>Param4</FirstExpression>
        <Operator>=</Operator>
        <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
      </MainBody>
    </group>
  </group>
  <operator>AND</operator>
  <group>
    <group>
      <group>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param5</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>0</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
        <operator>AND</operator>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param6</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
      </group>
      <operator>OR</operator>
      <group>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param7</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>0</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
        <operator>AND</operator>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param8</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
      </group>
    </group>
    <operator>AND</operator>
    <group>
      <group>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param9</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>0</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
        <operator>AND</operator>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param10</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
      </group>
      <operator>OR</operator>
      <group>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param11</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>0</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
        <operator>AND</operator>
        <MainBody>
          <FirstExpression>Param12</FirstExpression>
          <Operator>=</Operator>
          <SecondExpression>1</SecondExpression>
        </MainBody>
      </group>
    </group>
  </group>
</expression>
```

So you were definitely on the right track, as far as this goes, but I think the fact that we have to hack a results name into an internal undocumented member variable of `expr` is something of a red flag, and that more than likely, you will soon reach the limit of what you can do with `operatorPrecedence`.

You will probably have to implement your own recursive parser to full control over how all the elements and sub-elements get named.  You may even need to implement your own version of `asXML()` to control whether or not you get intermediate levels, such as the `<group>` tags shown above.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. This definitely got me farther but I'm still not there. I've tried to implement a recursive grammar.. I've added some additional info to my initial question with what I've tried in addition to your solution.